# How to split a string into an array based on every FOUR commas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm trying to split a string into an array based on the amount of commas, how do I do that? Say my string is as such;

```
var string = "abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwx, yza";
```

How can i split it so that it returns;

```
var array = ["abc, def, ghi, jkl,", "mno, pqr, stu, vwx,", "yza"]
```

Is this even possible?

Right now I'm using `var array = string.split(', ');`

But this adds the strings into the array based on every single comma.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `.match` instead of `split` - match (non commas, followed by a comma or the end of the string) 4 times:

```js
var string = "abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwx, yza";
const result = string.match(/(?:[^,]+(?:,|$)){1,4}/g);
console.log(result);
```

- `(?:[^,]+(?:,|$)){1,4}` - Repeat, 1 to 4 times:

  - `[^,]+` - Non comma characters
  - `(?:,|$)` - Either a comma, or the end of the string

If you want to make sure the first character is not whitespace, lookahead for `\S` (a non-whitespace character) at the beginning:

```js
var string = "abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwx, yza";
const result = string.match(/(?=\S)(?:[^,]+(?:,|$)){1,4}/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply. I just tested it out, and realized one thing, only the first instance shows 4 objects in the array, after that it shows 3 objects per array. hmm

Comment: Got it ! it works perfect now! thank you so much for that :D

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" in the question - I'm seeing 4 substrings per match (except at the last match, which could have 1, 2, or 3)

Comment: @mariamiller hasnt been ten mins yet. haha

Comment: @MariaMiller Keep in mind that answers can only be accepted after at least 15 minutes, no earlier https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer

Comment: oh, didn't know that... sorry

Comment: @UdhayanNair Your example output shows nested arrays. Is that not desired?

Comment: @showdev it is, and yeh, it works fine! it's the solution i'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, as long as it works for you. I'm just noting that this output structure doesn't match yours; it's an array of strings as opposed to an array of arrays.

Comment: I think the confusion is that your post has `[[abc, def, ghi, jkl,], [mno...`, did you mean `['abc, def, ghi, jkl,', 'mno...`?

Comment: whoops, I meant for it to be ["abc. def. ghi, jki", "mno, pqr, stu, vwx", "aaa, aaa, aaa, aaa"] so the answer is correct. let me edit my post.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is there any way i could message you via stack overflow? I have another question related to this, but would want to discuss it personally. cheers.

Comment: @CertainPerformance "Repeat, 1 to 4 times": Does this mean: "repeat as many times as possible, up to four and as little as one"?

Comment: @symlink Yes, the `+` is greedy. If it was lazy, with `+?`, it would repeat as few times as possible, only as many needed to match the pattern.

Comment: @UdhayanNair You can't message people in stackoverflow AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

`split` the string at `,`. Then create a generic `chunk` function which splits the array passed into chunks of `size` specified using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const str = "abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr, stu, vwx, yza",
      splits = str.split(/,\s*/),
      chunk = (arr, size) => Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) },
                              (_, i) => arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size))

console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk(splits, 4)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk(splits, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and reduce also to achieve this :

```
let array = str.split(", ").reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
      if(i%4 === 0){
         prev.push([]);
      }
      prev[prev.length - 1].push(curr);
      return prev;
   }, [])
```